# Deploy WebRTC Demo App on local server

Tags: webrtc

I would like to deploy the WebRTC demo app (https://apprtc.appspot.com) on a local server and run it together with the android WebRTC App.

I've downloaded the code from [here](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/#svn/trunk/samples/js/apprtc) but I'm a bit confused of how to run it in local.

Thanks in advance to everyone who will help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need install the Google Cloud SDK and run apprtc as an App Engine app (instructions [here](https://console.developers.google.com/start/appengine)) then open it from localhost, e.g. `http://localhost:8080`.